# Share auto-increment value from SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that inserts data on a table with an auto-increment id (name of 'requestid'). As I insert data into it using the procedure, I want to take the value of the auto-increment field and use it on another query to the same stored procedure. How do I do that? Thank you in advance for your time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Create_new_request]
       @employeeid                     INT                    , 
       @requestdate                    DATETIME               , 
       @deliverdate                    DATETIME               , 
       @totalcost                      MONEY                 

AS 
BEGIN 


     INSERT INTO dbo.Requests
          ( 
            EmployeeID                    ,
            RequestDate                   ,
            DeliverDate                   ,
            TotalCost                     

          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @employeeid                   ,
            @requestdate                  ,
            @deliverdate                  ,
            @totalcost                    

          ) 



END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Create_new_request]
   @employeeid                     INT                    , 
   @requestdate                    DATETIME               , 
   @deliverdate                    DATETIME               , 
   @totalcost                      MONEY,
requestid               INT             = NULL OUT                 

AS 
BEGIN 


 INSERT INTO dbo.Requests
      ( 
        EmployeeID                    ,
        RequestDate                   ,
        DeliverDate                   ,
        TotalCost                     

      ) 
 VALUES 
      ( 
        @employeeid                   ,
        @requestdate                  ,
        @deliverdate                  ,
        @totalcost                    

      ) 

 SET @requestid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: The scope_identity will return the last identity created, in this case the request id in the Requests table.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use auto increment instead use sequence to increment and then you can reuse that value anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can use also :

IDENT_CURRENT ('dbo.Requests')

Information about IDENT_CURRENT
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

Comment: -1 for recommending the not session-safe, when there are well know better alternatives (namely [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx))